# Google+ hangouts multiplayer app...?

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-hangouts

My question is how can i make a simple multiplayer game/multiuser app for google hangouts..?  please if anyone made this type of apps for google hangouts tell me how did he do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question that will likely get closed, but here are some tips.

Start with the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/) and also check out the showcase and then join the [Hangout developers community](https://plus.google.com/communities/104516377666905956948).

The API methods that you'll likely rely heavily on for developing this type of game are [sharedState](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/shared-state) and [sendMessage](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.data#gapi.hangout.data.sendMessage).

You can get app examples from the community and from the showcase.